# How do I submit a dynamically generated form with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

I have 2 forms. The first one is an async post that populates the data for form 2. I then want to submit form 2 synchronously so the users browser is redirected to a the new page. However the following code doesn't seem to be doing the job.

```
$('#Form1').ajaxForm({
    success: function(data) {
        //returns a complete form
        $('body').append((data));

        //the following works so I know the jquery selector is recognized
        console.log($('#Form2'));

        //however this does not work
        $('#Form2').submit()

    }
})
```

Is this not a valid method for submitting a form, or am I just missing something here? Thanks.

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: What is the content of the generated form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that form2 has a submit button with an id or name of "submit?"

Comment: *face-palm* Yup, you nailed it. Thanks!

Comment: It's a gotcha as old as javascript!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `$('#Form2')[0].submit()`, otherwise, you'll be calling the JQuery method used to bind to the submit event (entirely different matter, see: http://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Comment: `$('#Form2').submit()` will trigger the submit method, as per the link you gave us.